# Is it immoral seeing tutorials and documentation and other information about an technology you are not very familiar

Tags: new-job, job-offer, applications, productivity

Recently I graduated with a degree in Computer Science. I have being searching for jobs ever since in Web Development. I've seen a lot of job opportunities are asking for MVC knowledge, especially ASP.NET.

Fortunately, ASP.NET for me is not a problem, as I did a lot Web Forms, C# code and SQL, but never MVC, or any MVC project. So the last couple of weeks, I started to learn MVC for  myself, seeing tutorials on Youtube, Lynda.com and also on the original MVC website. My knowledge on MVC has increased exponentially, which is good, and an outsourcing consultancy has ask me to update my knowledge file (document which they provide for us to fill with all the knowledge we know) and CV.

**My question is if I started to work in a company that asks me to build an MVC website, is this immoral?** If I'm simply not up to task, I could do some research or seeing the documentation of an certain property or method. Besides my knowledge of creating an MVC project and the basics, they are still things that I don't know or understand correctly, and do not count in my favor.

I am a person that always wants to learn and always try to motivate myself to know how to do things. And yes I'm a junior web developer.

Thanks for any advice or information :-)

Comment: What definition of morality are you using here? Most people may have to learn things on the fly and pick it up as needed. Outright lying in resume or job interviews may get you fired in some places at times however.

Comment: I assume the OP means "unethical", not "immoral".

Comment: If that's your definition of "immoral", then everyone is software engineering and devops is overdue for a session in Hell. I don't mind going to Hell but I would be thoroughly insulted if I were told that I am going to Hell over your bizarre definition of what's "immoral"

Comment: First im not saying that is immoral im asking if it is immoral, im just asking from profissional and experience users opinion. One thing is having experience and formation on certain type of technology and other is you dont have any experience and you having studying on the last weeks about this technology, this difference is important to apply to a job. About Hell i dont comment it, if you get insulted its your problem not mine. One of the rules of life is if you don't know, you ask.

Comment: Since you don't know, let's enlighten you. Your definition of "immoral"is not just bizarre, it matches your spelling of "profissional"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it unethical to say I know a language or library when I have only seen tutorials and documentation?

(Paraphrasing your question. Please comment if I am incorrect.)

You should not say you have experience or knowledge you lack. This is clearly unethical.

However, if you possess related skills (such as your ASP.NET web forms, C# and SQL knowledge) and are confident you can learn the rest, still apply for the job if you want. If they test you (such as with a simple programming exercise), it will be apparent where your skill gaps are and the hiring company will make the decision whether to hire you or not. The worst that can happen is they hire someone else.

Remember too, as a recent graduate, the skill expectations are probably not too high. You will be expected to learn as you go, particularly about the non-technical and business related aspects of the job. Being someone that "always wants to learn and always tr[ies] to motivate myself to know the answer and know how" will probably count for a lot more than knowing ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

It's really up to you. Do you think you can build an MVC website? That's the real question. Not "Do you know everything right now that is required to build an MVS website". If only people did things who right now know how to do it, nothing would ever get done.

So you ask yourself: Can you get the job done? Do you know enough right now or can you learn quick enough to get it done? If the answer is Yes, go ahead. If the answer is No, obviously it will be found out eventually and that won't end well.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I see now that i havent express myself correctly. And yes its not immoral but unethical that i want it to say, but still most of the answers has help me to reshape my perspective how to answer on the interview, and how to apply correctly to a job.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not immoral to try to learn (which is the question you asked in the title).

It certainly *is* immoral to claim more knowledge than you have... and as @JBKing points out, doing so can be a Career Limiting Action.

If there's a technology that you've been exposed to but do not consider yourself fully qualified in, I'd recommend saying something like "some exposure to" or "limited experience with" in your resume. That indicates that you're familiar with the basics and can probably learn more quickly, while not promising more than you can deliver. You can then discuss exactly how much you do or don't know when you get to the interview.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if I started to work in a company that asks me to build
>   an MVC website, is this immoral?

The company has some responsibility to vet your knowledge of any technology before they allow you to work on any production code for a client. Of course, the more honest your answers to their questions should be as honest as possible - that is on you. Programming is a process of writing code, either you demonstrate some ability in this or you don't.  Hopefully, they just don't take your word for it.

Another place this is going to be an issue is in your estimations, budgets and other time billing for your clients. Again, they have some responsibility to get additional estimates to compare to yours. You may require more time (if you're honest and give yourself additional time), but as a first year developer, you may be more profitable if your hourly rate is low enough to compensate for the additional time you will take over someone with more experience.

Once everyone has all the information, they have some obligation to understand how software development and the billing process works. You'll have to decide if you've been honest and upfront about your situation.